# What does this sample CKEditor javascript function do?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

MVC5

Using the information from this [CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) I was eventually able to integrate an image selection process from an MVC method/view that displays a list of available images that could be inserted into a text area using CKEditor.

While the finished solution turned out to be preciously simple, the overall process was not particularly intuitive.  I will eventually post my solution as I am certain many relatively new MVC coders, such as myself, are looking for simple and straightforward solutions for this functionality.  But in the meantime,

The code below shows the relevant lines from **Example 2** at the link above, slightly rearranged.

```
<body>
  <button onclick="returnFileUrl()">Select File</button>
</body>

<script>
    function getUrlParam( paramName ) {    // Helper function to get parameters from the query string.
        var reParam = new RegExp( '(?:[\?&]|&)' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i' );
        var match = window.location.search.match( reParam );
        return ( match && match.length > 1 ) ? match[1] : null;
    }

    function returnFileUrl() {    // Simulate user action of selecting a file to be returned to CKEditor
        var funcNum = getUrlParam( 'CKEditorFuncNum' );
        var fileUrl = '/path/to/file.txt';
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( funcNum, fileUrl );
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

I never figured out how to use **getUrlParam()**.  I eventually just bypassed it and fed-through the variable **funcNum** with the exact parameter that had been passed into my image selector method.  As soon as I did that, the sample code from CKEditor worked great.

But what is that **getUrlParam()** function doing?  I only nominally understand RegExp, and this one completely escapes me.  Can anyone explain why it is even suggested?

Comment: I guess this is simulation as it states in the comment

Comment: Could be, but following their example, it doesn't work.  So... not a very good simulation.  But that aside it still begs the question what is that function trying to accomplish?

Comment: `getUrlParam`takes a `paramName` (as `q` in `http://google.com/search.php?q=term`), defines a RegExp that matches the param and captures its value into Group 1 (`match[1]`, e.g. `term`) that  is returned by the method. `window.location.search` gets the querystring part (e.g. `?q=term`) of a current window URL in JS. I'd replace the regex definition with a simpler `var reParam = new RegExp( '[?&]' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i');`.

Comment: @Alan, any news? Shall I post my explanation as an answer? I do not understand if that is all the help you need.

Comment: @Wiktor, I actually didn't understand your comment because of **my** limited regex understanding, so I intend to take some time to go step by step through the symbols to try to follow your explanation.  I didn't want to ask you to explain each symbol because that's on me, but if you want to explain feel free to do so.

Comment: I have not explained the regex, jut what the function does. :) What language are  you trying to convert to?

Comment: @Wiktor, I work in vb.net, but isn't this simply javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getUrlParam` takes a `paramName` (as `q` in `http://google.com/search.php?q=term`), defines a `RegExp` that matches the `param` and captures its value into Group 1 (`match[1]`, e.g. `term`) that is returned by the method. The `window.location.search` gets the querystring part (e.g. `?q=term`) of a current window URL in JS.

I'd replace the regex definition with a simpler

```
var reParam = new RegExp( '[?&]' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i');
```

The resulting regex will look like `[?&]q=([^&]+)` matching:

- `[?&]` - either a `?` or `&` (in your original code, it is `(?:[\?&]|&)`, matching either  a `?` or `&`, or a `&` - thus, I suggest shortening)
- `q=` - literal sequence of characters `q=`
- `([^&]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more characters other than `&`.

In VB.NET, you could use something like:

```
Private Shared Function getUrlParam(paramName As String) As String
    Dim reParam = "(?i)[?&]" & Regex.Escape(paramName) & "=([^&]+)"
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match("http://google.com/index.php?q=term", reParam)
    If match.Success = True And match.Value.Length > 1 Then
        Return match.Groups(1).Value
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

And call with `Dim res As String = getUrlParam("q")`.